# Rails Overriding Doorkeeper class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, overriding, doorkeeper

How can I override the `AccessToken` class of the Doorkeeper gem?

https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/doorkeeper/orm/active_record/access_token.rb

I already tried creating the class at models/access_token.rb

```
module Doorkeeper
  class AccessToken < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :resource_owner, class_name: 'OauthResourceOwner'

    include AccessTokenMixin

    def as_json(*)
      super.except!(:resource_owner_id).merge!(
        owner: {
          id: resource_owner&.owner_id,
          type: resource_owner&.owner_type&.tableize
        }
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced with same issue.
And add association in initializer

```
Doorkeeper::AccessToken.belongs_to :resource_owner, class_name: 'OauthResourceOwner'
```

Comment: If you have a `NameError: uninitialized constant Doorkeeper::AccessToken` issue: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/1319#issuecomment-582370730

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby classes are "open" which means that you're not overriding `AccessToken` but instead you are adding methods to `AccessToken`.

Comment: I know, but I cant even add methods. If I call Doorkeeper::AccessToken.last.resource_owner I got missing method

Comment: Safoff any thoughts?